# Adding more spells to champion of Gwynharwyf spell list

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, optimization

I have an interest in the champion of Gwynharwyf’s ability to cast its spells while raging.

> **Furious Casting (Ex):** Starting at 2nd level, a champion of Gwynharwyf can cast her champion spells even while raging. If she has another spellcasting class, she cannot cast spells from that class while raging, only the spells that she gains from her champion levels.

Unfortunately, the champion spell list is very lacking. (The spellcasting is the same as a cleric, but with no domains, very few spells per day, an extremely brief spell list, and a maximum of 4th-level spells.)

Thus, I would like to add spells to the spell list, and I’m seeking as complete a list as possible for ways to do that. Some are obvious-ish, such as getting a bonus domain, and others are less, such as the *Races of the Wild* prestige class skypledged, which gets access to a “divine spellpool” that it can pull cleric and druid spells from.

This kind of thing is [widely discussed for sorcerers](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?197165-Adding-Spells-to-Your-Class-Spell-List), but not so much for divine spellcasters since most of them are already casting whatever they like from an expansive list.

Requirements:

1. has to be compatible with furious casting, i.e. “champion spells.” Ruled to be concerned primarily with whether the spell is cast from a champion spell slot (rather than being strictly limited to the actual champion spell list or something).
2. has to be from a 3.5e source published by Wizards of the Coast (in a book, PDF, or web page doesn’t matter), or *Dragon*, *Dungeon*, or *Dragon Compendium*.
3. has to be available without recourse to epic rules.
4. does *not* have to be anything that a champion is likely or even plausibly going to qualify for. For instance, mage of the arcane order has “arcane” in the name, requires arcane spellcasting and advances arcane spellcasting, but the spellpool feature itself makes no requirement of being used only with arcane spellcasting.
5. does not have to concern itself with concerns of alignment or faith (e.g. the champion’s required CG alignment, Knight of Stars feat, or association with Gwynharwyf). There are ways around these, in theory, and in any event my game won’t necessarily be taking place in the official setting anyway.

Comment: Does your allegiance to the Court of Stars (due to the Knight of the Stars feat, a requirement for the prestige class) preclude your having a patron deity for the purposes of initiate feats? Or will the DM generously reskin initiate feats whose prerequisites you otherwise meet?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Good point, I’ll say we can ignore alignment and deity restrictions. Personally, I’d argue that Knight of the Stars is compatible with, at the very least, an Arborea patron deity, but since it’s unclear (and we can arguably overcome alignment issues with hellbred and/or Ordered Chaos), it’s easier to just ignore them. Updating.

Answer (score 3):

The Champion of Gwynharwyf (*CoG*) is a [Prepared divine spellcaster](https://dndtools.net/classes/champion-of-gwynharwyf/)  and gains the Furious Casting ability at 2nd level:

> Starting at 2nd level, a champion of Gwynharwyf can cast her champion spells even while raging. If she has another spellcasting class, she cannot cast spells from that class while raging, only the spells that she gains from her champion levels.

Anything that adds spells to your spells known will work. All the suggestions assume you have at least two levels in the *CoG* class. Some cover gaining domains on your *CoG*, so I've included Complete Divine's rules below.

Examples:

- [Mother Cyst](https://dndtools.org/feats/libris-mortis-the-book-of-the-dead--71/mother-cyst--1984/) adds 9 necrotic-* spells.
- Switch to [Sovereign Speaker](https://dndtools.net/classes/sovereign-speaker/) for up to 9 domains.
- Switch to [Contemplative](https://dndtools.net/classes/contemplative/) for up to 2 domains.
- Switch to [Deadgrim](https://dndtools.net/classes/deadgrim/) to gain disrupt undead, chill touch, detect undead, hide from undead, command undead, ghoul touch, halt undead, and vampiric touch.
- Switch to [Impure prince](https://dnd.arkalseif.info/classes/impure-prince/index.html) to gain disguise self, protection from evil, remove fear, calm emotions, lesser restoration, zone of natural purity, daylight, remove disease, nature's wrath, and restoration.
- The [Cerebrosis feat](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/hum_forgotten_realms/cerebrosis-t314.html) from Dragon #330 grants a number of unique spells.

I have some more leads, if they are viable I'll add them to this answer.

Complete Divine covers gaining Domains for non-Domain casters on page 20:

> If a noncleric enters a prestige class that allows access to a domain, the character still gains access to the domain. She can use the granted power bestowed by the domain normally. If she memorizes spells like a druid, paladin, or ranger, then she can simply choose to memorize one of that domain’s spells instead of one of her usual spells, but never more than one domain spell of each level.

I excluded the following because they only add one or two specific domains:

> [Divine Oracle](https://dndtools.net/classes/divine-oracle/), [Dracolyte](https://dndtools.net/classes/dracolyte/), and [Seeker of the Misty Isle](https://dndtools.net/classes/seeker-of-the-misty-isle/).

I excluded the following because they required 4th level *CoG* casting:

> [Celestial Mystic](https://dndtools.net/classes/celestial-mystic/) and [Sacred Exorcist](https://dndtools.net/classes/sacred-exorcist/)

Comment: Well,  now I know 3.5 has a 3rd level spell that can have a 31% chance of disappearing the caster from reality forever...

Comment: Dimension Rift-ing into unknown locations is hard stuff.

Comment: The destination actually had to be known,  I got the impression that the hard part was the shortcut you were taking was outside of reality itself, and you might miss the exit back in.